# want to go to SignUp page when clicked on SignUp from the App component in React can some one rectify the code accordingly

Tags: reactjs

```
App Component:

import LoginForm from "./Component/LoginForm/LoginForm";
import HomePage from "./Component/HomePage/HomePage";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

    function App() {
      const user = [{ username: "admin" }, { password: "admin" }];
      const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);

      useEffect(() => {
        const isUserLoggedIn = localStorage.getItem("isLoggedInn");
        if (isUserLoggedIn === "1") {
          setIsLoggedIn(true);
        }
      }, []);

      const loginHandler = () => {
        localStorage.setItem("isLoggedInn", "1");
        setIsLoggedIn(true);
      };
      const logoutHandler = () => {
        localStorage.removeItem("isLoggedInn");
        setIsLoggedIn(false);
      };
      // const saveData = (enteredUsername, enteredPassword) => {
      //   const userPassData = {
      //     'username':enteredUsername,
      //     'password':enteredPassword
      //   };
      //   return userPassData;
      // }
      return (
        <div>
          {!isLoggedIn && <LoginForm adminUser={user} onLogin={loginHandler} />}
          {isLoggedIn && <HomePage onLogout={logoutHandler} />}
        </div>
      );
    }

    export default App;

LoginForm Component:

import styles from './LoginForm.module.css';
import { useState } from 'react';
import SignUp from '../SignUp/SignUp';
    const LoginForm = (props) =>{

        const [enteredUsername,setEnteredUsername] = useState('');
        const [enteredPassword,setEnteredPassword] = useState('');
        const [isTrue,setTrue] = useState(true);
        const [isClicked,setIsClicked] = useState(false);

        const onChangeHandlerUsername = event =>{
            setEnteredUsername(event.target.value);
            if(event.target.value === enteredUsername){
                setTrue(true);
            }
        }
        const onChangeHandlerPassword = event =>{
            setEnteredPassword(event.target.value);
            if(event.target.value === enteredPassword){
                setTrue(true);
            }
        }
        const onSubmitHandler = (event) =>{
            event.preventDefault();
            if(enteredUsername === props.adminUser[0].username && enteredPassword === props.adminUser[1].password){
                props.onLogin();
                console.log(enteredUsername,enteredPassword);
            }
            else{
                setTrue(false);
                setIsClicked(true);
            }
        }
        const onClickHandler =()=>{
            setIsClicked(true);
        }
        return(
            <>
            <form onSubmit={onSubmitHandler}>
                <h1>Welcome</h1>
                <div className={`${styles.box} ${!isTrue && styles.wrong}`}>
                <h1>Login</h1>
                <input type='text' value={enteredUsername} placeholder='Enter Username' className={styles.email} onChange={onChangeHandlerUsername}></input>
                <input type='password' value={enteredPassword} placeholder='Enter Password' className={styles.email} onChange={onChangeHandlerPassword}></input>
                <div><button className={styles.btn}>Sign In</button></div>
                <div><button onClick={onClickHandler} type='button' className={styles.btn2}>Sign Up</button></div>
                <div><a href='#top'>Forget Password</a></div>
                </div>
            </form>
                {!isClicked? '' :<SignUp/>}
            </>
        );
    }
    export default LoginForm;
```

want to go to SignUp page when clicked on SignUp from the App component in React can some one rectify the code accordingly. Dont know where i am wrong can some one help me out.
There is SignUp button which when clicked based on the username and password if not same as that of the added user or Admin will go to the sign up page  to register for  the new user.

SignUp component:

```
import './SignUp.module.css';
    const SignUp = (props) =>{
        return(
            <div>
                <h2>SignUp page</h2>
            </div>
        );
    }
    export default SignUp;
```

Comment: what is happening if you click on signup now ?

Comment: its showing the content of SignUp page below the LoginForm but i want to show the signup page and not the LoginForm also when the username and password are equal to the hard coded username and password.i have modified my code a little bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are having your SignUp below the Form component if you need to render only one of them based on the `isClicked` then you can use the `ternary` operator to do it.

change your code as below

```
 <>
      {isClicked ? (
        <SignUp />
      ) : (
        <form onSubmit={onSubmitHandler}>
          <h1>Welcome</h1>
          <div>
            <h1>Login</h1>
            <input
              type="text"
              value={enteredUsername}
              placeholder="Enter Username"
              onChange={onChangeHandlerUsername}
            ></input>
            <input
              type="password"
              value={enteredPassword}
              placeholder="Enter Password"
              onChange={onChangeHandlerPassword}
            ></input>
            <div>
              <button>Sign In</button>
            </div>
            <div>
              <button onClick={onClickHandler} type="button">
                Sign Up
              </button>
            </div>
            <div>
              <a href="#top">Forget Password</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      )}
    </>
```

Also you should not be doing this

```
  const onChangeHandlerUsername = event =>{
            setEnteredUsername(event.target.value);

            // This will always be false because the state change wont reflect immediately.
            // Please remove this for both the username and password

            if(event.target.value === enteredUsername){
                setTrue(true);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Shyam for clearifying the thing....actually i in learning phase so thats why i got stuck.